# setting a delegate for a custom view inside a uitableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, delegates

I am not sure if that's possible.

So I have a custom cell - which inside contains a custom uiview. This UIView is a view that displays bar diagrams. So I want to set the dataSource, and the delegate for that UIView.

If I use that code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"StatsCell";

    StatsTableViewCell  *cell = (StatsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StatsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }



    cell.barChart.dataSource = self ;
    dell.barChart.delegate = self;
}
```

I get a warning :

```
 Assigning to 'id<JBBarChartViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'StatsViewController *const __strong'
```

How do I do that? And then, if that's possible - since that delegate method will be called for any of the cells - how do I distinguish for which of them is called?

I am using JBChartView from [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jbchartview).

Thanks.

Comment: why not make cell to be it's child delegate and datasource?

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela can you give me an example? i am not sure I get what do you mean.

Comment: e.g. in `StatsTableViewCell`'s `awakeFromNib` or similar you set the `self.barChart.delegate = self;`

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela same warning but for a TableViewCell this time. and the data are not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JBBarChartView`'s `delegate` property is of type `id<JBBarChartViewDelegate>`.  In order to set an object to be the delegate without getting this warning, you must define that class as conforming to the `JBBarChartViewDelegate` protocol as such:

```
@interface YourClass <JBBarChartViewDelegate>
```

Once you do this, you'll see warnings for any `@required` protocol methods that your class hasn't implemented, if any.  You'll need to implement these methods.

As @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela recommends, it probably makes more sense for the cell to be the delegate/datasource rather than the tableview.

---

You could also get rid of the warning by casting the object as such:

```
cell.barChart.delegate = (id<JBBarChartViewDelegate>)self;
```

**But I'd highly recommend against this.**  If `self` isn't defined as conforming to the protocol, you won't get warnings for missing `@required` protocol methods, and as such, you'll likely get a "unknown selector" crash.